# Conditional formatting not working when value is pasted

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm using Google sheets. I just want the cell to turn green when there is something in it. Pretty basic. It works if I type a value in but not if I paste a value from somewhere else. The ID numbers I'm working with are long so I don't want to retype them because it wastes time and creates room for error.

Answer (score 0):

To preserve conditional formatting when pasting to a cell, you can do one of the following

1. **Choose `Paste values only`**

#### OR

2. **Double click within the cell and paste your value/number**

[image]

Comment: marikamitsos I have done that but it is still not working, unfortunately. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: What is the formatting of the cell you copy from **and** what is the formatting of the cell you paste on? Also, please edit your question (as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64797312/1527780)) and give couple of examples of the numbers you want to copy as well as the result you get when pasted .

Comment: This is indeed working for me. I have defined a range with conditional formatting, and copying only the values does indeed work as @marikamitsos said. Share maybe a sample sheet to check that out.